# Eclipse warning: "<methodName> has non-API return type <parameterizedType>"

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, warnings

My co-worker and I have come across this warning message a couple times recently.  For the below code:

```
package com.mycompany.product.data;

import com.mycompany.product.dao.GenericDAO;

public abstract class EntityBean {
    public abstract GenericDAO<Object, Long> getDAO();
    //                                       ^^^^^^      <-- WARNING OCCURS HERE
}
```

the warning appears in the listed spot as

```
EntityBean.getDAO() has non-API return type GenericDAO<T, ID>
```

A Google search for "has non-API return type" only shows instances where this message appears in problem lists.  I.e., there's no public explanation for it.

What does this mean?  We can create a usage problem filter in Eclipse to make the message go away, but we don't want to do this if our usage is a legitimate problem.

Thanks!

**EDIT**: This warning doesn't have to do with the parameterization, as this declaration of `getFactory()` also results in the same warning:

```
public abstract class EntityBean {
    protected DAOFactory getFactory() {
        return DAOFactory.instance(DAOFactory.HIBERNATE);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error I get (I'm the coworker) is a little different: "Foo implements non-API interface Bar". The error highlights Foo, and Foo is defined as "public class Foo implements Bar"

Comment: Where is T specified, and how is GenericDAO defined?  The specification in the error message doesn't match the method signature.

Comment: @Steve:  It appears that this isn't related to parameterization, as methods that return non-parameterized types also get the warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.

These classes (`GenericDAO` and `DAOFactory` as return types) and `EntityBean` were in different packages.  One of the packages (the one containing `EntityBean`) was listed in the `Export-Package:` section of the manifest file, and the other package (`DAO`s) was not.  The net effect is that the `DAO` classes were non-API and were being returned by an API type.

Thanks all, especially to JRL for orienting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the following Eclipse docs: [API rules of engagement](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/api-usage-rules.html) and [API Errors and Warnings Preferences](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/reference/api-tooling/preferences/ref-errorswarnings.htm) ?

Comment: I haven't, but I will.  Thanks.